# I want to process tens of thousands of columns using Spark via sparklyr, but I can't

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sentiment-analysis, sparklyr

I tried using `sdf_pivot()` to widen my column with duplicate values into multiple (a very big number) columns. I planned to use these columns as the feature space for training an ML model.

Example: I have a language element sequence in one column (words), which I wish to turn into binary matrix of a huge width (say, 100,000) and run a sentiment analysis using a logistic regression.

**The first problem** is that by default `sparklyr` does not allow me to make more than 10K columns, citing possible eeror in my design.

**The second problem** is that even if I override this warning and make lots of columns, further calculations last forever on this very wide data.

**Question 1:** is it a good practice to make extra wide datasets or I should work differently with so deep feature spaces, while using the power of fast parallel calculations with Spark?

**Question 2:** is it possible to construct the vector-type feature column avoiding the generation of a very wide matrix?

I just need a small example or practical tips to follow.

https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1322

Comment: what is the dimension of your data on which you want to run logistic regression ?

Comment: @Mustufain, it is not really a question about the ML method (it could be an L1 regularized Log.Reg, prefaced by a feature selection routine using Chi-Square or something), but rather a question of how to construct the vector-type feature column and not getting stuck with too heavy calculations of the wide dataframe. I cited100K different features as a practical example.